# Is this form safe?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, security

I have this form by which a user sends me an email. I don't know if it is secured, or if issues with security appear only if sql is involved...

html:

```
<form id="form4" action="send_mic.php"  name="form4" method="post" >

           <textarea name="message4" cols="4" rows="4"  id="message4" ></textarea><br />

           <input type="text"  id="name4" name="name4" value="" /><br />

           <input type="text"  id="email4" name="email4" value=""  /><br />

          <input type="submit" value="" id="submit" />

</form>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form4').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: validate
    });

    function validate(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var name = $('input[name=name4]').fieldValue();
        var email = $('input[name=email4]').fieldValue();
        var message = $('textarea[name=message4]').fieldValue();

        if (!name[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for name');
            return false;
        }
        if (!email[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for email');
            return false;
        }
        if (!message[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for message');
            return false;
        }

        else {

        $("#content").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).html("<img src='images/postauto3.png'/>").fadeIn(2000);
        });

        var message = $('textarea[name=message4]').val('');
        var name = $('input[name=name4]').val('');
        var email = $('input[name=email4]').val('');

            } 
    }

});



    </script>
```

php:

```
<?php
        if($_POST){
                $email = $_POST['email4'];
                $name = $_POST ['name4'];
                $message = $_POST ['message4'];
                // response hash
                $ajaxresponse = array('type'=>'', 'message4'=>'');

                try {
                        // do some sort of data validations, very simple example below
                        $all_fields = array('name4', 'email4', 'message4');

                        foreach($all_fields as $field){
                                if(empty($_POST[$field])){
                                        throw new Exception('Required field "'.ucfirst($field).'" missing input.');
                                }
                        }

                        // ok, if field validations are ok
                        // now Send Email, ect.

                        // let's assume everything is ok, setup successful response
                        $subject = "New Contact";
                        //get todays date
                        $todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;

                        $message = " $todayis \n
                        Attention: \n\n
                        Please see the message below: \n\n
                        Email Address: $email \n\n
                        Message: $message \n\n

                        ";

                        $from = "From: $email\r\n";


                        //put your email address here
                        mail("contact@....ro", $subject, $message, $from);

                        //prep json response
                        $ajaxresponse['type'] = 'success';
                        $ajaxresponse['message'] = 'Thank You! Will be in touch soon';  
                } catch(Exception $e){
                        $ajaxresponse['type'] = 'error';
                        $ajaxresponse['message'] = $e->getMessage();
                }
                // now we are ready to turn this hash into JSON
                print json_encode($ajaxresponse);
                exit;
        }
?>
```

So, are there any security problems when using forms to send emails? Is this ok?
Thanks!

Comment: You might consider using `filter_var` function to check email sent (and sanitize it), check if email sent is not a trash mail, but in worst case, you could just NOT answer to this contact

Comment: I remember reading somewhere about ensuring that you add in some checks to ensure that no one is injecting cc and bcc fields into the mail header. If they do this, then they can send emails to whoever they wish through your web form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could add a captcha to prevent spam.
2. You could protect against email injections by using:

   filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Comment: where exactly should I add this line of code? after   $all_fields = array('name4', 'email4', 'message4');   is it ok?

Comment: After all fields would be perfectly fine. In fact, I'd recommend it because you'll want to make sure that you're receiving an email POST field before you try to validate it.

Comment: and this will protect me against sending spam to others? like people here are saying..

Comment: It'll protect against email injections (people CC'ing etc). It won't protect against spam. Only a captcha can help mitigate the effects of spam.

Answer (score 6):

In general, rule of the thumb should always be: **NEVER trust user provided data.** And no, your code is not bullet proof. Since you do not verify nor sanitize user input and you use `mail()` at the same time you are vulnerable. User can easily feed you with crafted value for `email4` filed. Since you use form data directly, then email4 can be used to inject additional mail headers to your outgoing mail. It these headers would be `BCC:` or `CC:` or even `TO:` then then you would be simply acting as spam relay. For example if I post this

```
some@address.com
CC: spamvictim1@foo.com, spamvictim2@foo.com, spamvictim3@foo.com,
X-Spam-Owned: Whoa
```

as your `email4` then your header would end looking like this:

```
To: some@address.com
CC: spamvictim1@foo.com, spamvictim2@foo.com, spamvictim3@foo.com, 
X-Spam-Owned: Whoa
```

to post multiline data you simply glue texts with CRLFs.

To avoid security holes like this you should consider dropping `mail()` and use something more clever that would take care of something like this too (not that `mail()` is bad, but you need to know what you are doing as it is rather low than high level function). I suggest using PHPMailer or similar package. You should always verify user provided data (especially ensure that single-line fields, like subject are really single line - stripping CRLFs suffice). Add captcha as you are open to automated form submission.

Answer (score 1):

I think this form is safe, mean that no one can really h@ck your website throught this form.
But you need to add somethings for better result: 
1. You should also check the post variable in php server side, mean that you should check if email / name / message is valid of not
2. You should add some captcha to prevent spam

Answer (score 1):

You can additionally wrap your server side code with

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  /* special ajax here */
  die($content);
}
```

This will ensure the ajax request is coming on the server.

And please mind your ID that you are using in one of your jQuery selector in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are not working with database, there could be security problems in email sending. Of course you can't be hacked by this form, but the problems will occure when the user will input something like this in EMail field:

```
email-address1@example.com  // there is a new line here
CC:email-address2@example.com,email-addresses3@example.com,.............................email-addressesn@example.com
```

so the best you can do is sanitizing all the input fields for mail function, to prevent such spam delivery. And as @WebnetMobile.com has already sad, **never trust user inputs**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a security issue in there, since you are not modifying anything on your server side. Might be an issue with spam though. Add some captcha to it. The rest looks ok.

Comment: and what about email injections?

Answer (score 0):

You should add captcha , client side and server side validation in form